# Simplifying a trig function in with a little trig help?

Tags: linear-algebra

In the first line, the trig COS is in the problem but disappears in the second line after simplifying.

How do you get that?

[image]

Comment: Because the dot product is the product of lengths times the cosine of angle.

Comment: see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DotProduct.html

Comment: ok. Its known to me now. thankyou

Answer (score 3):

The dot product for 2 vectors is defined to be $$u\cdot v= ||u||\times||v||\times \cos\theta$$
The work just simplified it to a dot product.